# P5.js - createGraphics() leads to strange results with small screen size

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I've been trying to solve this problem for days. I simplified the problem with this simple code :

```
let graphicCanvas
let ctx
let speed = 1
function setup(){
    cnv = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight)
    cnv.style('display', 'block');
    graphicCanvas = createGraphics(800,800)
    ctx = graphicCanvas.canvas.getContext('2d')
    
}
function draw(){
    ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas,0,0,800,800,0,speed,800,800)

    graphicCanvas.noStroke()
    graphicCanvas.fill(255,0,0)
    graphicCanvas.circle(100,100,50)
    image(graphicCanvas,0,0)
    
}
```

This code is supposed to show the trails,of a red circle, that is getting longer after each loop:
[Red trails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leAyv.png)

The problem is that this code only works on large screens. With small screens I end up with this result : [Red circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gGhy.png)

I don't know if the problem comes from the `createGraphics()`, the `drawImage()` or the `image()`.

I already tried to use graphicCanvas.push() and graphicCanvas.pop() but nothing change. How can I get the "Red trails" result for every screen size ?

(As a foreigner, please excuse me for the english mistakes)

Comment: is there any specific reason you need to reference the canvas and use the creategraphics function? That might be messing you up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not screen size, but pixel density. Because you are using the `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage` function instead of `p5.js` function the graphics is actually scaled 2x when it is drawn. Here's an example that should work on any screen:

```js
let graphicCanvas;
let ctx;
let speed = 1;

function setup() {
  pixelDensity(1);
  cnv = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  cnv.style("display", "block");
  graphicCanvas = createGraphics(800, 800);
  ctx = graphicCanvas.canvas.getContext("2d");
}

function draw() {
  ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 0, 0, 800, 800, 0, speed, 800, 800);

  graphicCanvas.noStroke();
  graphicCanvas.fill(255, 0, 0);
  graphicCanvas.circle(100, 100, 50);
  image(graphicCanvas, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

That said you might want to consider avoiding the native `CanvasRenderingContext2D` functions altogether and use p5.js functions that preserve support for pixel density:

```
let graphicCanvas;
let ctx;
let speed = 1;
function setup() {
  cnv = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  speed = pixelDensity();
  cnv.style("display", "block");
  graphicCanvas = createGraphics(800, 800);
}
function draw() {
  graphicCanvas.copy(0, 0, 800, 800, 0, speed, 800, 800);

  graphicCanvas.noStroke();
  graphicCanvas.fill(255, 0, 0);
  graphicCanvas.circle(100, 100, 50);
  image(graphicCanvas, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It worked perfectly !